# Air Print is very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, airprint

I'm working on a iOS kiosk type application that is utilizing Air Print to print a 10-ish page document.

This document is taking a very long time to print (more than 1 minute) and people are walking away before the print job is finished because they think it's done. It's also printing the first two pages, waiting about 20 seconds, and then printing a few more. This is when people are walking away.

As a test, I printed a longer and very image intensive document from a windows machine, to the same printer and on the same wireless network. This took less than 20 seconds, so it's not the printer. Also, the wifi network for testing this is very strong, and both the printer and iPad are near the wireless router.

I made sure the print document is in Grayscale, and tried everything I can to slim down the document, but it always takes the same amount of time to print.

For creating the print job, I have a custom class to create the print document, which takes no time at all to create.

Below is the code that is actually connecting to the printer and sending the job. The only thing funky is that I am storing the printer instance globally so that the customer doesn't have to select a printer for each print job.

This does all work, it's just too slow. Any advice on how to speed up printing?

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

printController.delegate = self;

printController.printPageRenderer = [[KioskPrintRenderer alloc] initWithCustom:_currentCustom];

UIPrintInfo *info = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
info.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;
info.jobName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"customID%@", _custom.Id];

printController.printInfo = info;

if ([customAppDelegate sharedPrinterFlag] ==FALSE) {

    [self savePrinter];

}

else{

    [[customAppDelegate sharedPrinter] 

     contactPrinter:^(BOOL available){

     }];

}

if ([customAppDelegate sharedPrinter]) {

    [ printController printToPrinter:[customAppDelegate sharedPrinter]  completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *controller, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

        [self ClosePrintView];



}];

}
```

--Edit--

Some additional findings:

Hard wiring anything (ipad to router, printer to router, etc) didn't make any difference in speed.

This is printing to an HP LaserJet Pro 400. Could there be something with the printer itself, even though printing from a windows device works perfectly?

Comment: Is it quicker printing from other applications?

Comment: It does seem slow from other applications (safari) as well, so it may not be app specific.